# different count results between `find` and fzf (command-line fuzzy finder)

Tags: bash, terminal, find, fzf

I really can't get my read around why I'm seeing different count results between `find` and [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

```
$ find ./ -iname '*tablet*' -print | wc -l
2683
```

**fzf**

```
$
>tablet
 2910/6024
```

[image: fzf example]

what do I seem to be missing here?

Comment: If I were facing this problem, I would save the two results in files and make a diff. Very likely the question will be answered.

Comment: That's a good idea @Kent - I just don't know how to print the results from fzf..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍♂️ forgot to make the fzf search `exact` (hence it's fuzzy by default)

```
$
>'tablet
 2683/6024
```

now they match!

---

On the fzf repo it actually states

> fzf will launch interactive finder, read the list from STDIN, and write the selected item to STDOUT.
>
> `find * -type f | fzf > selected`

So it's find under the hood